# Get value from a dictionary until next key is reached in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

The title is not explaining my problem at all, but I'll show you here.
I am parsing emails from GMail account using Google API. From each email I need to get some values. The email body is formed like:

Object: Something.

Procedure: Something.

...

(Many fields)

...

Request: (A value that can be single-row or multi-row)

To get all the fields I need, I do this:

```
    for msg in msg_list:
        data_dict = OrderedDict()

        msg = msg.replace('\r','')
        msg = msg.split('\n')

        for row in msg:
            row = row.split(":")

            if row[0] in key_list:
               data_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

        dict_list.append(data_dict)

return dict_list
```

The problem occurs when I parse the specific field 'Request', because it can be multi-row and with the 'msg.split('\n')' I get this:

"Request: (first row of field)",
"(second row of field)",
...

"(n-th row of field)"

In the Ordered Dict goes only the first row as value.
How could I get the entire content? 
I hope it is well explained.

Here it is the form of a `msg (already splitted)` taken from the `msg_list`:

> '',
>
> 'La pratica Ticketing TSX - 2016-049044 necessita di essere
>   lavorata.',
>
> '',
>
> 'Procedura: MATRIX - Enterprise Data Warehouse',
>
> 'Oggetto: Mancata esecuzione algoritmo stima reddito (DASTIRED)',
>
> 'Perimetro: Specifico',
>
> 'Priorit=C3=A0 richiesta: Alta',
>
> 'Tipologia Richiesta: Segnalazione Anomalia',
>
> 'Sottotipologia Richiesta: Altro',
>
> '',
>
> 'Emergenza:',
>
> '',
>
> "Richiesta: Ad oggi l'algoritmo mensile di stima reddito (sequence
>   DASTIRED)",
>
> "non risulta ancora essere stato eseguito. Solitamente l'esecuzione",
>
> 'automatica avviene entro i primi 10 giorni del mese dopo che tutte
>   le',
>
> 'dipendenze sono state soddisfatte ma attualmente vedo ancora il job
>   nello',
>
> 'schedulatore con stato W. Chiedo la cortesia di verificare
>   perch=C3=A9 non =',
>
> 'sia',
>
> 'ancora stato eseguito (problemi su flussi attesi?) e di provvedere
>   al',
>
> 'recupero. Grazie',
>
> '',
>
> 'UO Richiedente: INF',
>
> 'Autore: UT07080 - SPADINI MATTEO',
>
> 'Data richiesta risoluzione:',
>
> 'Scadenza SLA : 24/06/2016 14.12.36',
>
> '',

Thank you.

Comment: What determines the end of the `Request:` field - end of string/end of file/start of another delimiter/etc...?

Comment: @JonClements A blank row

Comment: Okay - so does a blank line effectively separate entries? ie: - there's more than one record in a file somewhere and you're trying to create a list of dicts from them? (If I'm understanding correctly?)

Comment: @JonClements Exactly, I create a list of dicts with this records, but with split for '\n' I lose the record of `Request:`. It would be great if I could regroup that record only for that key.

Comment: adding a sample data of `msg_list` would be great.

Comment: @EduardDaduya I'll add it in the question ;D

Comment: @EduardDaduya Added! Where 'Richiesta' is 'Request' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your code should do the trick:

```
import collections
key_list = ['Object','Procedure','Request']
dict_list = []
msg1 = 'Object: the object\nProcedure: the procedure\n'
msg1 += 'some data\nsome more data\n'
msg1 += 'Request: request line 1\nrequest line2\nrequest line3\n'
msg2 = 'Object: another object\nProcedure: another procedure\n'
msg2 += 'some more data\nsome even more data\n'
msg2 += 'Request: another request line 1\nanother request line2\n'
msg_list =[msg1,msg2]

for msg in msg_list:
    data_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    msg = msg.replace('\r','')
    msg = msg.split('\n')
    for row in msg:
        row = row.split(":")
        if row[0] in key_list:
            key = row[0]
            data_dict[key] = row[1]
        elif key in key_list:
            data_dict[key] += row[0]
        else:
            key = ''

    dict_list.append(data_dict)

#show results
for i in dict_list:
    for k,v in i.items():
        print k,v
```

The above produces:
Object  the object
Procedure  the proceduresome datasome more data
Request  request line 1request line2request line3
Object  another object
Procedure  another proceduresome more datasome even more data
Request  another request line 1another request line2

Comment: I got this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment. Should I use `global`?

Comment: Just initialize it in the for msg in msg_list: loop. key='' should be fine

Comment: One more little problem, in this way I get also the next field, why?